# How to Delete "Duplicate" Records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete certain records from my table that I consider "duplicates". They're not exactly duplicates as not every column value are the same. Rather, the logic is something like this:

> If `col_a` and `col_b` have the same value across several rows, and
>   `col_c` (which is a timestamp) is within, say, 5 minutes of each
>   other, then delete all rows except the row with the earliest
>   timestamp.

**Example Data:**

```
id    col_a    col_b     col_c
1     foo      bar       2016-01-01 00:00:00
2     foo      bar       2016-01-01 00:00:12
3     foo      bar       2016-01-01 00:00:22
4     foo      bar       2016-01-05 00:00:00
5     apple    banana    2016-01-01 00:00:00
6     apple    banana    2016-01-05 00:00:00
```

In the above example, I want to delete id = 2 and id = 3. Is this possible to do in MySQL?

Comment: What if you have multiple records with same cola_a and col_b. The time difference between the 1st and last records is let's say 10 minutes (outside of the 5 min tolerance), but there is less than 5 minute difference between the consecutive records? Do you delete all, but the earlies records, or after 5 minutes from the earliest one do you want to delete the other ones? Would it be acceptable to delete all duplicates for every 5 minute intervals and preserve only the earliest timestamp from that interval?

Comment: Yes, I think so. "Legitimate" records are at least 2 hours apart, and often days apart. Due to a very odd bug in my app, more than the necessary records are getting inserted. It's not really causing any problems in the application, but I just want to clean up the table a bit.

Comment: So, as confirmation... if we have records (same col_a and col_b), with col_c times in a series that are 4 minutes apart...  06:15, 08:30, 08:34, 08:38, 08:42, etc.   we'd keep the 06:15, and the 08:30, but delete the 08:34, 08:38, 08:42.  That is... as long as there is another row (same col_a,col_b) that is within the previous five minutes, we should remove that record. Even if that previous record is also going to be deleted.

Comment: I think you're right. There are over a million records in this particular table I need to clean, so it's hard to say for sure. I need to investigate.

Comment: I suggest you first write a `SELECT` statement that identifies the rows to be removed, and once you have that tested and verify that it's returning the rows you want, then convert that into a DELETE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could do the trick

```
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE ID IN(
select t1.id
FROM tab as t1 JOIN tab as t2
ON t1.col1=t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
WHERE DATE_DIFF(MINUTE, t1.col3, t2.col3) < 5 
AND DATE_DIFF(MINUTE, t1.col3, t2.col3) > 0)
```

Join the table and get all the duplicates. In those duplicates select only the ones that satisfy the time constraint. Note: `> 0 and not >=0`

Comment: I think the `DATE_DIFF` function is specific to SQL Server. The closest equivalent in MySQL is `TIMESTAMPDIFF`. Though in MySQL, we'd likely do the comparisons without the function, just using expressions like `d.col_c < t.col_c + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`